# TcpClient.EndConnect throws NullReferenceException when socket is closed

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, connection, tcpclient

I am trying to connect to my server with a `TcpClient.BeginConnect / TcpClient.EndConnect` combo. However, some things don't work as they should.

The scenario is as follows:

- Call to the `TcpClient.BeginConnect`
- Server is intentionally offline (for testing purposes) - thus no connection can be made.
- I close the application (`client.Close()` gets called in the process which [closes the socket which in turn stops the async operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145129.aspx))
- `TcpClient` connection **callback method** happens giving `IAsyncResult`
- Call to the `TcpClient.EndConnect` method with the given `IAsyncResult`
- `NullReferenceException` happens on `EndConnect` (**?**)
- Since the last form (window) was closed, the app should exit - however it does not, at least not until `BeginConnect` operation completes (which is strange, as callback has already been called).

[image: exception]

What happens here is that a `NullReferenceException` is caught. As you can see from the picture above, neither `client` nor `ar` are `null`. The problem is that the [MSDN documentation for the EndConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.endconnect.aspx) does not mention the case in which this exception is thrown.

So basically, I have no idea what is going on. The problem is that I am forced to wait for the app to close (as if the connection operation still waits for a timeout). *If a server is online, it connects and disconnects just fine*.

**What does** `NullReferenceException` **in this context mean**? How to avoid `BeginConnect` operation to block the application closing in case the connection can't be established?

---

**Additional notes** (*requested in comments*):

Here is the code to create the client (client is a member variable:

```
public void Connect()
{
    try
    {
        lock (connectionAccess)
        {
            if (State.IsConnectable())
            {
                // Create a client
                client = new TcpClient();
                client.LingerState = new LingerOption(false, 0);
                client.NoDelay = true;

                State = CommunicationState.Connecting;

                client.BeginConnect(address, port, onTcpClientConnectionEstablished, null);
            }
            else
            {
                // Ignore connecting request if a connection is in a state that is not connectable 
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Close(true);
    }
}
```

Also the Close method:

```
public void Close(bool causedByError)
{
    lock (connectionAccess)
    {
        // Close the stream
        if (clientStream != null)
            clientStream.Close();

        // Close the gateway
        if (client != null)
            client.Close();

        // Empty the mailboxes
        incomingMailbox.Clear();
        outgoingMailbox.Clear();

        State = causedByError ? CommunicationState.CommunicationError : CommunicationState.Disconnected;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the InnerException give any more information about what was NULL?

Comment: @Tremmors Nope. InnerException is null. No help from the StackTrace too (onTcpClientConnectionEstablished > EndConnect). :(

Comment: Yes, clearly a framework bug. In the case that the TcpClient is closed before EndConnect() is called it is supposed to throw ObjectDisposedException. I seem to get NullReferenceException instead the first one or two times, then it will start throwing ObjectDisposedException as expected. I suggest you simply handle it in the same was as you would ObjectDisposedException (i.e. "connection timed out/failed/whatever other reason you called Close()"). However, I don't know whether any resources might be leaking here since EndConnect() is not completing. Probably nothing the GC can't deal with. :)

Comment: How has this not been fixed in .NET 4.8 ?

Answer (score 1):

The `NullReferenceException` is probably due to `TcpClient.Client` being null.

If you were to follow the [MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145193.aspx) for `TcpClient.BeginConnect` and pass the`TcpClient` object as the state object:

```
 private void onConnEst(IAsyncResult ar)
 {
      try
      {
           TcpClient client = (TcpClient)ar.AsyncState;
           if(client!=null && client.Client!=null)
           {
                client.EndConnect(ar);
           }
      }
      catch(Exception ex){...}
 }
```

This should handle the case when `Close()` is called before the Callback.

Going back to your problem - how long does it take for the application to eventually close?

Comment: Why do you cast ar.AsyncResult? Did you mean ar.AsyncState? Anyway, my client is a private member so I don't need to pass it to the async method. I am currently unable (i.e. not at work) to check if the TcpClient.Client is null. However, based on my memory and previous experience, if I don't call client.EndConnect the application still hangs when I try to close it. It usually lasts the same as is the connecting timeout (~20s). And if I don't close the app during connection attempt, the BeginConnect will fail after the same time.

Comment: Oops - you are correct, `ar.AsycResult` should be `ar.AsyncState`. Post edited to reflect changes.

Comment: Would you be able to post how you are constructing the TcpClient, and your BeginConnect? Do you bind the socket before you BeginConnect? Also, not that it should matter, but what .Net Framework are you using?

Comment: I have updated the question to fill the missing pieces. I am using .NET 4.

Comment: Although I didn't run your code exactly, Client.Close() does not take long at all.

I would suggest commenting out the TcpClient portions of your code(for testing purposes only) and see if you still experience the delay.

Outside of that, there might be something fishy going on with multiple threads locking on `connectionAccess` that is causing the delay, which would make sense if you didn't experience the delay while stepping through the code.

Comment: I've already tried to do exclude any TcpClient code, then it works just fine. Like I said, the time it takes for the app to close corresponds to the time needed for the BeginConnect to fail after no connection was made (timeout). Therefor, I conclude that it is that async BeginConnect thread that remains active. About the deadlock, this is not the problem, because those are the only two places the lock is obtained and from what you can see, Close (in a catch block) is not enclosed in this lock.

Answer (score 1):

This obviously a bug inside the TcpClient class. I have also faced it. TcpClient.Dispose may set Client field to null but EndConnect does not expect that.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might want to consider elaborating a bit more on the details of the bug to make your answer a bit more thorough for other people who may come along this question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and ended up using this code. I am not sure if it will hold with the IASyncResult interface, but there may be a similar way to run this check. I do notice that your ar.AsyncState == null, so perhaps try starting there, i.e. is it null when you connect properly?

```
private void connConnectCompleted(AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        // Something didn't work...abort captain
        CloseSocket();
        Console.WriteLine(this.GetType().ToString() + @":Error connecting socket:" +  e.Error.Message);
        return;
    }
    // Do stuff with your connection
}
```

EDIT: Sorry I didn't realise I didn't post what generated my AsyncCompletedEventArgs, which is more related to what you are doing. You will see the reason why I was wondering as to ar.AsyncState being null.

```
private void OnConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    if (OnConnectCompleted == null) return; // Check whether something is using this wrapper
    AsyncCompletedEventArgs args;
    try
    {
        Socket outSocket = (Socket) asyncResult.AsyncState;

        // Complete connection
        outSocket.EndConnect(asyncResult);

        args = new AsyncCompletedEventArgs(null);
        OnConnectCompleted(this, args);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        args = new AsyncCompletedEventArgs(e.Message);
        OnConnectCompleted(this, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: AsyncState is used to pass some custom data to the callback method. I don't have such need so that's why it's null. It can't produce an error. I don't understand your example (it's incomplete). IAsyncResult has no error, and I guess you should provide the code for the CloseSocket() method as it is your own custom method. Othwerise, I don't know how your code example could be helpful.

Comment: CloseSocket() just fires off a couple of events to notify any other parts of program, then runs .Close() on the socket.

Answer (score 0):

This is [a know bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1080927/objectdisposedexception-exception-from-tcpclient-class).

You should be receiving 'ObjectDisposedException' instead of 'NullReferenceException'.